# Auto enhance UIImageView with no rotation

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview, swift5

I have been at this for two days now and hopefully, you can help me out. I am trying to auto-enhance an image from UIImageView. The following code is rotating and resizing images SOMETIMES and I'm having a hard time determining when or why. From the lack of posts on the topic, I feel like I must be missing something super simple. Thank you ALL!

```
// my UIImageView is self.imgOut 

var enhanceImg = CIImage(image: self.imgOut.image!)

let filters = enhanceImg!.autoAdjustmentFilters(options: nil)

for filter: CIFilter in filters {
  filter.setValue(enhanceImg, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
  enhanceImg = filter.outputImage!
}

let enhancedImg = UIImage(ciImage: enhanceImg!, scale: self.imgOut.image!.scale, orientation: self.imgOut.image!.imageOrientation)
self.imgOut.image = enhancedImg
```

Comment: are you using different images for this or always the same image? when are you calling the code in your project? I tested the code and ran it in viewDidAppear and saw the scale effect take place

Comment: Different images - some from the camera and some from the camera roll. I am running it from a button action.

Comment: how is the imageView created? does it have storyboard constraints? in the case of constraints, setting this might allow the scaling to happen: imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

Comment: sorry, the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints for the enhancedImg should be set to false

Comment: Nope, thanks man ...but still rotating and zooming :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone comes across this - the fix is to use a cgImage:

```
    let coreImage = CIImage(image: self.imgOut.image!)
    var enhanceImg = CIImage()
    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)

    let filters = coreImage!.autoAdjustmentFilters(options: [.enhance: true])

    for filter: CIFilter in filters {
        filter.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        enhanceImg = filter.outputImage!
    }

    let filteredImageRef2 = ciContext.createCGImage(enhanceImg, from: enhanceImg.extent)
    self.imgOut.image = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef2!, scale: self.imgOut.image!.scale, orientation: self.imgOut.image!.imageOrientation)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [in docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1437792-autoadjustmentfilters), `autoAdjustmentFilters` got input `options: [CIImageAutoAdjustmentOption : Any]? = nil`

So you need to specify options (exclude `level` option)
`level` is for orientation
`crop` is for zooming

```
let filters = enhanceImg!.autoAdjustmentFilters(options: [.level: false, .crop: false])
```

Comment: Oh, that's should work out. Can you send an archive with photo samples, which was flipped or cropped, to got it reproduced?

Comment: It’s part of a much larger project. Let me try it in a new one and see.